# Can I change the default parameter ':id' generated by routes in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have checked a lot of similar questions out there. Mostly the answers are showing override `to_param` method. But that's not what I want.

Let's say `resources: users`

`rake routes`

```
edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)              users#edit
user GET         /users/:id(.:format)                   users#show
PUT              /users/:id(.:format)                   users#update
DELETE           /users/:id(.:format)
```

Then back to my `UsersController`, I can get the `id` param from `params[:id]`. But this is not I want, I want it to be `params[:user_id]` . It's impossible according to the routes above.Because there is no `:user_id` parameter from the route. Is there any way that can help?

Comment: why do you care? Then maybe we can help come up with a solution.

Comment: @JesseWolgamott because in my routes file,there is a nested resources with `users` and `collections`. When I was dealing with collections, I can use `:user_id` as the param. But when it comes to 'users',I must use ':id' as the param to find a user... it's getting complicated...

Comment: Ahh. Ok, so you should either not use nested resources, or be cool with the idea that resources use the "ID" of the model to find the model.

Answer (score 1):

In general, Rails makes your life easy if you agree to go along with its conventions, and hard otherwise.  So I'd recommend leaving this one alone.

But if you really want the param to be `:user_id` - say for readability reasons or something - you can just "alias" it in a before_filter:

```
params[:user_id] = params[:id]
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do something to the default with `:path_prefix`, I'll have a play and update if I find a way.

You can do this manually though if needed by defining individual matches in your routes instead of using the resource generator:

```
match 'users/:user_id/edit' => 'users#edit'
```

This will resolve the url `/users/1/edit` like so:

```
Started GET "/users/1/edit" 
Processing by UsersController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"user_id"=>"1"}
```

Comment: I guess there is no easy ways for it... anyway. I will give it try.